# python- finding total number of items of certain range in a list

Tags: python

I have a list with many floats in Python. I want to know how many floats there are between any two integers. What's the easiest, most effective way to do this?

example.py
- How do I determine that there is 3 floats between int(1) and int(8).

```
between_List = [1, 1.2, 1.8, 1.45, 8]
```

Comment: Please edit your question it causing a lot of confusion and be specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply sum how many times an element is the the range 3-4:

```
l = [3.4,4.5,3.2,5.6]

print(sum(3 <= ele <= 4  for ele in l))
2
```

Or using numpy:

import numpy as np

```
l = [3.4, 4.5, 3.2, 5.6]
arr = np.array(l)

print(((3 <= arr) & (arr <= 4)).sum())
2
```

If you want to check if you actually have a float also use issinstance:

```
  print(sum(3 <= ele <= 4 and isinstance(ele,float) for ele in l))
```

If you actually want to count the total number of floats in between two actual integers:

```
l = [1.3, 3, 3.4, 34.5, 3.2, 4, 5.6]


def find_fs(l, i, j):
    try:
        start, end = l.index(i), l.index(j)
        return sum(isinstance(ele, float) for ele in islice(l, start + 1, end))
    except IndexError:
        return 0
print(find_fs(l,3, 4))
3
```

Comment: @VigneshKalai, where does it say my approach is wrong?

Comment: @VigneshKalai, the question is not clear as to whether the OP specifically wants only objects of type `float`. And if there's something wrong with an answer, explain what it is, don't just tell the answerer to read the question again. EDIT: Whoops, assumed you were the OP.

Comment: I see where you are coming from the question was unclear.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham my mistake I thought  he was asking for something different sorry again

Comment: @PadraicCunningham any how you could check if the the elements are float as op stated ` how  many floats there are between any two integers.`

Comment: @VigneshKalai, do you mean `and isinstance(ele,float)`? Or starting at the index where 3 is and counting how many actual floats appear between that in the index of 4?

Answer (score 3):

As others have posted, `sum(3 <= x <=4 for x in l)` will give you the answer in O(n) time for any list `l`. However, if you know that `l` is sorted, you can find the answer in O(lg n) time.

```
import bisect
# number of values 3 < x < 4
x = bisect.bisect_right(l, 3)
y = bisect.bisect_left(l, 4)
answer = y - x

# or, number of values 3 <= x <= 4
x = bisect.bisect_left(l, 3)
y = bisect.bisect_right(l, 4)
answer = y - x
```

Comment: I was just going to post the same

Comment: I didn't check if there are any off-by-one errors in this; feel free to post a corrected version if I got any details wrong.

Comment: Nope, mine was pretty much identical, I don't see any reason it would fail

Comment: @chepner, this returns the number of items between 3 and 4 _exclusive_, whereas the `sum()` method you included is _inclusive_. To change that, replace the calls to 'bisect_right()` and `bisect_left()` with the other one.

Comment: Good point; you can get the inclusive count (which I almost posted first) by using `bisect_right` with the upper bound and `bisect_left` with the lower bound.

Comment: nice method but it should only check `floats` and not `integer ` will this do that

Comment: @VigneshKalai, that's still not quite clear, but if that is what someone wants to do, they could still use this method to narrow down the list before iterating over the sublist.

Comment: @VigneshKalai Instead of passing `l`, just strip all non-floats first: `l2 = [ isinstance(x, float) for x in l]`, then use `l2` in place of `l` in the calls to `bisect_{left,right}`. (Which does, of course, kill the O(lg n) guarantee.)

Comment: @chepner just pointing out his request `I want to know how many floats there are between any two integers` so I think you can make the chane in your answer as separate segment :)

Comment: It also says he has a list of floats, not a list of floats and other things, so I feel it's safe to assume every item is a float.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to sum the elements which are in the range, and check for the type. **The `type` check is needed since the ranges may have integers in between them** (eg: all floats between 1, 4).

```
>>> lst = [1, 2.2, 3, 3.3, 3.4, 3.7, 4, 5.5, 6]
>>> st, end = 3, 4
>>> sum(st < x < end and type(x) == float for x in lst)
3
```

and between 1, 4:

```
>>> st, end = 1, 4
>>> sum(st < x < end and type(x) == float for x in lst)
4
```

Comment: This specifically checks that the values are of type `float`. I would assume that's not desired, but either way it should be pointed out.

Comment: both of you could be right his question was unclear.

Comment: @Cyphase Yeah, I was editing for that. The OP asked for _how many floats there are between any two integers_, so had added the check. If the numbers are consecutive, the check is not needed, but otherwise it is.